# PDFBox Android: getting Fatal Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError on calling PDDocument.load method

Tags: java, android, pdfbox

I'm using PDF Box Android library to load pdf documents and then using it to extract text from regions on page currently opened using PDFTextStripperByArea. Mostly it works fine but in some cases I'm getting this **Fatal Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError**.

`document = PDDocument.load(mFile, MemoryUsageSetting.setupTempFileOnly());`

And onDestroy of Activity i'm calling

```
document.close();`
```

I know one solution could be increasing the heap size but that has its own disadvantages. Is there an way we can optimize this and fix this outOfMemory Exception?

Comment: Please share the file. While I can't help, I'll test whether this also happens in PDFBox for desktop. Does it also happen when using the standard text stripper?